# Making an API call in Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, api, nsurlsession

I've been scouring examples looking to pull some ideas together, I've come up with this although I'm not getting any output. It never enters the do which leads me to believe I have an issue with my call.

Can anyone shed some light on this for me or lead me to an appropriate location with more information on API calls in swift 2.0? Examples of this are quite sparse.

```
    let url : String = "http://www.fantasyfootballnerd.com/service/nfl-teams/json/test/"
    let request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
    request.URL = NSURL(string: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    print("Start")
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        do {
            let jsonResult: NSDictionary! = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
            print("In method")
            if (jsonResult != nil) {
                // process jsonResult
                print("Data added")
            } else {
                print("No Data")
                // couldn't load JSON, look at error
            }
        }
        catch {
          print("Error Occured")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check out: http://www.ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/swift/parse-json-deserialization/ - shows you how to process the results and also gives you an option using Alamofire

Comment: Ah this is great, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing just one thing. You need to start the request:

```
// call this after you configure your session
session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

    // process results

}.resume()
```

Comment: Getting an error "value of type NSURLSession has no member resume" I must be missing something else in here

Comment: `resume` is a method on the `NSURLSessionTask` returned from `dataTaskWithRequest`

Comment: @user3344880 There was a mistake, I just updated my answer.

Comment: @Macondo2Seattle So this totally works, however it errors out due to it not being secure. I would prefer to conform to proper protocol when it comes to this and editing the plist file to allow an exception for http just doesnt seem like a solid idea. Is there a more secure way that apple pushes to accomplish that? Appreciate your help!

Comment: @user3344880, seems like the server you connect to actually supports https, so just changing the url to `https://www.fantasyfootballnerd.com/service/nfl-teams/json/test/` should do the trick :)

Comment: No luck, @Macondo2Seattle. I think I'm going to need to add an exception for it. Unless I can find another method. Thanks for the help with this!

Comment: Got it @Macondo2Seattle, the test URL I was using didnt support JSON. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: @user3344880 Glad I could help! :D